# can a guest run code and make a independent server using live share in VS2019?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-liveshare

I am new using ***Live share*** in Visual Studio 2019 and I am working on a large project using ASP.NET MVC. I invited some collaborators to work on my project but the problem is that... they can only run the web app whenever I run my server locally(I configure the same port). I cannot leave the server running forever because they need to modify the C# code and server needs to restart and It is annoying that they asks me to restart the server every second. I want to know if there is a way that they can run my shared code using live share in their computers independently of mine?

***Or... is Live share useless for remote working?***

I cannot find solutions in google, there are **zero** information about it. I tried:

1. How to run live share server locally
2. Run live share server independently of host server
3. can guest run program or web app independently of host server live share
4. live share run program or web app locally
5. live share run web app without host server port